# Reportviewer toolbar buttons are disabled/inactive

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I am facing a strange problem, I am working on report viewer version 12 in asp.net using vb.net as code behind, but the toolbar buttons previous, next and print are inactive/disabled can somebody help me with this, your help is much appreciated.

[image]

Thank you.